# ToggleButton status

Tags: excel, vba, togglebutton

I am using Excel Ribbon toggleButton. Based on it's on/off status I do some processing in the Excel cell in the SheetSelectionChange event. I am not able to get the status of the toggleButton from the cell without accessing my settings file which is an unnecessary overhead. Let me present a snippet of the code.

Global variable could be an option. But can I have something better?

```
Private Sub mExcel_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal theSheet As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
'++
' Call the C++ Code.
'--
'If (isbtnpressed) Then  ** <-- This is where i want to check the ToglgeButton status
' I don't want to read the settings file for every cell click. **
    Dim flagVal As Boolean
    'IsValidData goes to C++ for validation
    If IsValidData(Target.Application.ActiveCell) Then
        LoadMyListForm Target.Application.ActiveCell
    End If
'End If

End Sub
```

onAction Events (two)

```
Public Sub IxlRibbonGetButtonStateByTag(theControl As IRibbonControl, ByRef isbtnpressed)
'++
'Get ShowOnClick button state, callback for getPressed
'
' Arguments:
'    theControl - The ribbon control that fired the OnAction request.
'    IsPressed - Button status
'--
On Error Resume Next
isbtnpressed = (ReadFromSettingsFile (theControl.Tag, "0") <> "0")

End Sub
```

And

```
Public Sub IxlRibbonToggleSettingByTag(control As IRibbonControl, IsPressed As Boolean)
'++
'callback for onAction
'
' Arguments:
'    theControl - The ribbon control that fired the OnAction request.
'    IsPressed - Button status
'--
On Error Resume Next

If IsPressed Then
    WriteToSettingsFile control.Tag, "1"
Else
    WriteToSettingsFile control.Tag, "0"
End If

End Sub
```

the UI XML looks like

```
            <toggleButton id="tb_IxlToggleButton"
                label="My Label"
                tag="MyLabel"
                getPressed="IxlRibbonGetButtonStateByTag"
                onAction="IxlRibbonToggleSettingByTag"
                imageMso="ControlToggleButton" />
                <button id="MyLabel"
                    tag="MyLabel"
                    onAction="IxlRibbonToggleSettingByTag"/>
```

> I have gone ahead and used global variable as the way out as has been
>   suggested in the comment section by @Pᴇʜ

Comment: What is wrong with a global variable for that? It would work as expected and I see no disadvantages in it. So in which way can anything be better than that?

Comment: I was thinking of some get/set function to get the toggle status instead of a global var.

Comment: Er, I agree with @Pᴇʜ `Public Variable` is the **best** option. Just 2 lines of code and then use that variable whereever you want it. **Alternative**: Simply add a worksheet in the `Private Sub Workbook_Open()` event and store the value there and then delete the temp sheet when you close the workbook in the `Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)` event? And if you do not want to add/delete sheet then simply hide the worksheet? Much easier than writing to a text file or the registry...

Answer (score 1):

If `Public` variable not wished, a convenient way would be to keep and reed its status in Registry. The Toggle button can also be set when the application starts, according to the memorized status:

1. Create some constants at the module level:

   ```
   Public const MyApp as string = "MyApp Name"
   Public const MyAppSett as string = "MyApp Settings"
   Public const TglVal as string = "Toggle_Val"
   ```
2. Transform your event code in:

   ```
   Public Sub IxlRibbonToggleSettingByTag(control As IRibbonControl, IsPressed As Boolean)
    SaveSetting MyApp, MyAppSett, TglVal, cStr(IsPressed)
   End Sub
   ```
3. Create a function to rapidly return the status (reading in Registry):

   ```
   Function TglStatus() As Boolean
       Dim strToggle As String
       strToggle = GetSetting(MyApp, MyAppSett, TglVal, "Nothing...")
      If strToggle <> "Nothing..." Then
           TglStatus = CBool(strToggle)
      Else
           TglStatus = False 'for the case before memorizing of something...
      End If
   End Function
   ```
4. And use it like this:

   ```
   If TglStatus Then
        'do something for true
   Else
        'do something else for false
   End If
   ```

Comment: @Pᴇʜ: Correct! Thanks! I will adapt the code in this suggested way...